# jq transform to array and sort

Tags: json, jq

Suppose I have the following input.log file:

```
{"foo": "1", "foo2": "2"}
{"foo": "3", "foo2": "4"}
{"foo": "5", "foo2": "6"}
{"foo": "7", "foo2": "8"}
```

I want to parse this using **jq** and sort the result based on the value of some common key, lets say the **"foo"** key.

How could I accomplish that?

Comment: Use `--slurp` and `sort_by`: `jq -sc 'sort_by(.foo)[]' input.log` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/23UWBL3IlWT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort, you need an array, which you can obtain using `--slurp`/`-s`.

```bash
jq -sc 'sort_by( .foo )[]' input.log
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BHxDP19jvdD) on jqplay